# How to submit the form and then disable the Submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML snippet :

```
<form  method="post" id="form-post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form-labname">Lab Name</label><br>
    {{form.labname}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form-cidr">CIDR Block</label><br>
    {{form.cidr}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form-budget">Budget</label><br>
    {{form.budget}}
  </div>
 <input id='submit' type='submit' class="btn btn-primary"  
  style="background-color:#3facdb;border-color=#3facdb;" value='Submit' />
</form>
  </div>
<input type="hidden" id="myemail" name="variable" value="{{ emailid }}">
</input>
```

I need the submit button to be disabled after the form values have been submitted. I tried many cases but even though the button gets disabled, the form is not submitted. I also need to submit the hidden "myemail" value.

This is my javascript :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#form-post").submit(function () {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    return true;
   });
});
```

Although this disables the submit button, the values are not submitted.

Comment: Show you jquery/javascript code

Comment: _I also need to submit the hidden "myemail" value._ then move `myemail` hidden element inside the `form` element

Comment: I have added the js code.. Check it out now

Answer (score -1):

Create a Boolean variable and make it true on button click.
Also add [disable]=variable_name to your button HTML declaration.